# No Battery Available

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, charging

I have a MacBook Pro 15", early 2011. Earlier this week, I brought it home and plugged it in, and there was an X through the battery. Did an SMC reset, and it started charging again. The next day it stopped again, and the message in the menubar said "No Battery Available." I opened up System Information, and under Power it said there was no battery installed.

Did another SMC reset and System Information was unable to load information for Power. I recently did another SMC reset, upgraded to Yosemite, and am still getting the no battery available symbol. But now this is what's showing up in System Information:

[image]

Is my battery completely dead? Is there any way to recharge it, or do I need to replace it?

UPDATE: I forgot to note, I did an AHT on the machine a couple days ago, and it said there was nothing wrong with the hardware. If the battery was jostled loose, wouldn't AHT flag it?

Comment: You battery is not connected at all, the interior plug is not working.

Comment: @Buscar웃 Can I fix this myself, or do I need to bring it in?

Comment: would you happen to know what the battery information was when it was charging?

Comment: yes you can, and the new battery is about $100 https://www.ifixit.com/Store/Mac/MacBook-Pro-13-Inch-Unibody-Mid-2009-to-Mid-2012-Battery/IF163-019 lets hope it is not your logic board failing where the SMC chip sits on it. That would cost much more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably knocked the battery connector out. Here's a [link](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Pro+15-Inch+Unibody+Late+2011+Battery+Replacement/7511) to a repair guide to replacing the whole battery, which is more than you need. Do steps 1 and 2 to open your computer up, and then make sure the battery connector in Step 3 is 100% plugged in. If it's fully plugged in and it's still not working, the battery itself is probably shot.

Comment: Unless the back's been taken off and the battery connector's been removed and pushed back into place *badly*, there's no way it will work loose by itself on a unibody MacBook as the connection is very secure and takes a degree of effort to remove...

Comment: We don't know what symlink's computer's been through. I figured I'd offer some degree of hope before recommending all-out replacement.

Comment: It's always worth exploring the various possibilities, but the chances of the battery connector working loose (and the Mac still being in one piece afterwards) are next to nil. Battery failure is however an all too common occurrence...

Comment: @user24601 I forgot to mention that I ran an AHT and there were no hardware errors found. If the battery were knocked loose, an AHT would have caught this, right?

Comment: @user24601 I followed the steps in the guide, wasn't able to get the screws out to fully unseat my battery, but I unplugged the connector and plugged it back in. Working fine now. Fingers crossed!

Answer (score 1):

Possible bad news, you should have gotten Replace Battery warnings way before, that you could not missed.

What it indicates is your Logic board is failing where the SMC chip sits on it. You can open it and take battery out, then place it back in, but that is slim hope.

Before you spend a fortune in replacing the logic board:

There is a small circuit build in the battery that reports its presence and status to the SMC chip that then reports it to the system (you). If that one is dead then just replacing the battery would do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I can't see the image you posted right now (due to proxy filtering) but if it says "Service Battery" you can either live with it or buy a new battery. Chances are the battery's integrated status monitor is either correctly identifying a battery failure or the the monitor itself has failed. There isn't a "fix" for this other than replacement. If your battery dock icon is showing an "**X**" then, as above, live with it or replace it.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem, where the battery was showing as not existing. Took it to the Apple Store, and their tests showed no battery, which confused them.

They took it in the back and returned a few mins later. It was the battery power meter on the side of the MacBook Pro, you know the one that lights up with 6 tiny white lights?  The battery pack is connected thru the meter to the power port. The meter had a problem and thus disconnected from the battery.

Battery was fine, but the system could not access it.

Suggest you get Apple to look at it.